# Flex Project vs Flash Professional Project

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, project, builder

I've just got my Flash Builder 4 and now I want to create a project. The Flash Builder 4 IDE shows me 2 options: (1) Flex Project, (2) Flash Professional Project.

I know that "Flex Builder" was the former name of "Flash Builder", however, I don't know which of the 2 project types mentioned above is more advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this documentation about creating [projects in Flash Builder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e972ff2927b12e1411968f-7fff.html#WSc5cd04c102ae3e972ff2927b12e1411968f-7ff7).  Read this documentation on the [Flash Professional project type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSc5cd04c102ae3e97-6e5d439512e1414e588-8000.html).

You're formal question was "which of the 2 project types mentioned above is more advanced." and I'm not sure how to answer that.  They are different, and used for different purposes.  I might compare them to a stapler and tape.  Both can attach two pieces of paper together, but I wouldn't consider one more advanced than the other.  They are just different.

Comment: oh, Flash Professional Project is to change existing fla file. i'm clear now. tks flextras :)